# Python: Microsoft Exchange Approve/Reject email via EWS(using exchangelib)

Tags: python, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

Tell me please, is there an opportunity to approve/reject moderated emails in ms exchange directly from python? Now I am studying the exchangelib library, but I have not found a solution yet.
Thanks!

Comment: It's not implemented in exchangelib, but for reference here's the enhancement request tracking the issue: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/604